# How do I sum up when complying to two conditions and then put the summed data in a new data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a data frame with dates, categories, and time durations. I want to sum the time durations if the entries have the same date and the same category.

Input:

```
Date        Duration   Category
01/01/2021  0.1        Entertainment
01/01/2021  1.4        Working
01/01/2021  2.1        Entertainment
02/01/2021  7.9        Sleeping
02/01/2021  1.2        Working
02/01/2021  2.8        Working
04/01/2021  6.2        Sleeping
```

Output:

```
Date        Entertainment   Working   Sleeping
01/01/2021  2.2             1.4       0
02/01/2021  0               4.0       7.9
03/01/2021  0               0         0
04/01/2021  0               0         6.2
```

I have more categories so if you can allow it to easily add new categories. The code I have doesn't work at all so please help me out thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pivot_table()`:

```
out=(df.pivot_table('Duration','Date','Category',fill_value=0,aggfunc='sum')
       .rename_axis(columns=None)
       .reset_index())
```

**OR**

you can use `pd.crosstab()`:

```
out=(pd.crosstab(df['Date'],df['Category'],df['Duration'],aggfunc='sum')
       .fillna(0)
       .rename_axis(columns=None)
       .reset_index())
```

output of `out`:

```
      Date      Entertainment   Sleeping    Working
0   01/01/2021  2.2             0.0         1.4
1   02/01/2021  0.0             7.9         4.0
2   04/01/2021  0.0             6.2         0.0
```